cumulative sum(running sum) in SSAS tabular model
I have a big problem
I use this code to find cumulative (running total) in the SSAS tabular but I give this result:
=CALCULATE(SUM (TEST_X[SALE]),FILTER(ALL(TEST_X[DATES1]) ,TEST_X[DATES1]<=max(TEST_X[DATES1]) ))
would you please help me to solve it?
"I need to calculate the cumulative sum of my table data."
